# Disable assignment rule(s) and default owner when using email-to-case?

Tags: email2case, assignment-rules

I have a scenario where Case Owner is changed only using Apex code, rather than through assignment rules + default owner. We've been able to make it work for a couple of different Case creation scenarios.

However, when using email-to-case (at least on-demand) the assignment rules + default owner are applied.As this happens after the Apex code we use (an after insert trigger), the Case Owner gets overridden.

We have implemented a workaround, using a "dummy" assignment rule. It works, but it's not a very nice solution. We have some other ideas, but they may require more effort.

We'd like to understand our options. Is it possible to prevent the assignment rules + default owner from being applied in the first place when using email-to-case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this as follows

- Recognize that triggers run before assignment rules and E2C will run assignment rules.
- In before insert trigger, set custom field `Bypass_Assignment_Rules__c` to true for those use cases where assignment rules should be bypassed.
- Create assignment rule (at position 1) that takes any Case with `Bypass_Assignment_Rules__c = true` and assign to a "in-transit queue"
- This change in ownership will re-execute your triggers that can detect `ownerId = inTransitQueueId` and then do the assignment as you desire while also turning `Bypass_Assignment_Rules__c`to false.

Comment: Thank you for the quick anwer! This makes a lot of sense, so I have what I need now.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

For Email To Case the assignment rule will fire after the triggers.
So if we update the case owner in the insert trigger , then it executes the assignment rule and the case owner will be based on the Assignment rule entry not the one updated in the trigger.

*How I solved the problem!!!!*

1. In the after insert trigger accumulated all the ids that need the
   owner update.
   Passed those ids to a future method.
   In the   future method done the necessary check and assigned the new case
   owner as per my requirement.

It works fine for me :)

I tried many other ways to tackle the problem, but it is future method that helps to solve the problem.