# Sequence of execution in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, order-of-execution

If I change a record owner using apex, will any assignment rules run, and change the owner as specified by the rule? I am asking because assignment rules come after triggers in execution sequence.

By default I have kept 'Assign using assignment rule' checkbox unchecked.

Comment: Ideally it should not change it. Maybe try it and let us know if you are facing a specific issue.

Comment: do you have any active assignment rules?

Comment: yes...I have a active assignment rule

Comment: But my understanding is lead assignment rule should not run for every DML in apex

Comment: it depends how you have handled in your configuration and apex code

Comment: How can i stop assignment rules from executing after Owner change in Apex trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment rules run when:

1. An API client inserts a Lead and specifies an [AssignmentRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_assignmentruleheader.htm). This is typical for Marketing Automation Systems like HubSpot or Marketo.
2. A DML statement is executed that includes `DmlOptions` with property [AssignmentRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm?search_text=assignmentruleheader) set.
3. The user clicks 'assign using active assignment rules' on the OOTB Lead edit page.

These three rules tell SFDC to execute assignment rules. Just doing a DML insert without any AssignmentRuleHeader set explicitly or implicitly does not run the assignment rules.

If you are trying to coerce the ownerId in the before trigger when one of the three use cases above apply, the assignment rules will smash your coercion.  [A workaround (the example is for Case but principle applies as well to Lead) is here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/157379/2602)